# How to make VSCode's autocomplete as powerful as PyCharm?

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, pycharm

**Problem**

I love VSCode's look, but it's Python autocomplete is not that satisfactory.
For example, when I import `numpy` and `plotly.graph_objects`, VSCode can't deduce what's in these modules:

[VSCode doesn't know the linspace fuction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuxPH.jpg)

[VSCode has completely no idea what's in there and lists some nonmembers. Suggestion may vary from time to time.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGIsg.jpg)

While PyCharm does a good job with both modules:

[PyCharm knows the linspace function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JB7pV.png)

[PyCharm lists the members correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uycd0.png)

I remember that **VSCode once did as good as PyCharm**, but I don't why and how to make VSCode powerful again.

---

**VSCode configurations**

Python extension settings:

```json
{
    "python.jediEnabled": false, // I tried both true and false
    "python.analysis.memory.keepLibraryLocalVariables": true,
    "python.analysis.memory.keepLibraryAst": true
}
```

I waited for the Python extension to fully load and analyze in background. I tried both to enable and disable the Visual Studio IntelliCode extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you tried both language servers and VS Code made you reload then you have tried the options currently available to you from the Python extension. We are actively working on making it better, though, and hope to having something to say about it shortly.

But if you can't wait you can try something like https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-pyright.pyright as an alternative language server.

Comment: I've already enabled pyright, but the autocompletion still doesn't work for some 3rd party libraries (but I do remember it worked perfectly once, I hope VSCode can do better in the future). Thanks for all your and your team's hard work. It's a little bit harsh to compare VSCode to PyCharm since the latter is a specialized Python IDE. VSCode does a pretty good job on most libraries.

Comment: The comparison is fine. We hope to eventually have better auto-complete than PyCharm.  

Answer (score 0):

It might be a problem related to Pylance. By default, Pylance only looks for modules in the root directory. Making some tweaks in the settings made sure everything I import in VSCode works as if it's imported in PyCharm.

Please see:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67099842/6381389