# 'Import "Path.to.own.script" could not be resolved Pylance (reportMissingImports)' in VS Code using Python 3.x on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, visual-studio-code, pylance

It is a [similar situation I'd encountered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61383869/12298276) several months ago using [pylint](https://www.pylint.org/) prior to [pylance](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release):

My `python 3.9x` - script (using `VS Code` on `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS`) starts with the following import of custom "tools":

```
import sys
sys.path.append(
    '/home/andylu/Dokumente/Allgemeines_material/Sonstiges/Programming/Python/Scripts/'
)

import General.Misc.general_tools as tools
```

Now, `Pylance` states:

```
Import "General.Misc.general_tools" could not be resolvedPylance (reportMissingImports)
```

This happens even though during the program execution the module is being imported perfectly fine.

Thus, to ensure making `Pylance` understand that this is an existing module-path, in addition to the `sys.path.append(..)` - approach, I added the following to the `settings.json` - file:

```
{
    ...
    // Possible values: "Jedi", "Pylance", "Microsoft", "None".
    "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
    // NOTE on changing from microsoft to pylance language server: python.autoComplete.extraPaths --> python.analysis.extraPaths
    // Docs: https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#unresolved-import-warnings
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "/home/andylu/Dokumente/Allgemeines_material/Sonstiges/Programming/Python/Scripts"
    ],
    ...
}
```

Yet, I still get the `reportMissingImports`-message even though it's correctly being imported.

A workaround I found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/VisualStudioCode/comments/i3mpct/how_to_tell_pylance_to_ignore_particular_linefile/g5bkx9u?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) works well (appending `# type: ignore` to the import-statement):

```
import General.Misc.general_tools as tools  # type: ignore
```

Nevertheless, it's just a workaround which is why I'm looking to solve the root of this issue. Technically, it is [the same workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61383869/12298276) I employed earlier to get rid of similar warning messages from `pylint`. Probably it's something inherent to the `VS-Code` `settings.json` - configuration, since using `VS-Code` is the constant factor here.

---

**EDIT on additional measures which didn't resolve the problem:**

I added

```
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/home/andylu/Dokumente/Allgemeines_material/Sonstiges/Programming/Python/Scripts"
```

to my `~/.bashrc` - file, which enables me now to import the module directly in a `python`-shell from terminal without the previous `sys`-path manipulation. This however applies only to the global system python environment, but not to any virtual environment.
In order to change the sys-path there, I followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15282950/12298276), while my particular virtual environment "scrapy_course" is open, like so:

```
(scrapy_course) andylu@andylu-Lubuntu-PC:~/$ add2virtualenv /home/andylu/Dokumente/Allgemeines_material/Sonstiges/Programming/Python/Scripts
```

This command applies for [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which mananges virtual environments in conjunction with [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) neatly.
Now, I can run my aforementioned script within the current environment even without the `sys.path.append(...)` prior to import the module, YET `pylance` still doesn't recognize the paths correctly and shows me the same warning as before.

---

**EDIT on `"python.analysis.useImportHeuristic": true`:**

I've had this option constantly activated in my global `settings.json` - file and still I didn't notice any effect. I will keep you updated once this should change, or finally a (different) solution crosses my way.

---

**EDIT on suppressing/disabling the Pylance 'reportMissingImports' linting-message:**

I've found out [how to suppress a specific Pylance-linting-message](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68210700/12298276) altogether, if that is of your interest as a workaround. Especially in my current situation, I need to utilize [pylint](https://www.pylint.org/) in [parallel](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/13315#issuecomment-701913450)  anyway, so I don't depend on Pylance's linter at all.

Comment: will it resolve if you do `import General`, what if you add the path to `PYTHONPATH` before starting VSC. Maybe PyLance only wants relative paths in `"python.analysis.extraPaths"`

Comment: Thanks for your hint. It made me try out additional measures (see EDIT of my initial post above). I still get the same warning message from pylance. Apart from that, an absolute path should always work as far as I'm concerned, but even if this was the issue, now there are all `python`- and `sys`-paths set within my project-`venv`, and still `pylance` doesn't recognize it.

Comment: then consider filing an issue with PyLance not adhering to `PYTONPATH`, but how do the virtual environments merge the local and system installed modules, PyLance can handle these

Comment: Now, for some reason, it stopped throwing the warnings. I don't know how it got resolved, but for now I closed the issue posted on the `pylance` GitHub website: https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/724

Comment: i get the same linting issue. It appears as though there is still no solution other than to add `# type: ignore` at the end of the import statement.

Comment: I tried to recreate the issue (on Windows) but it works for me by adding the full path to `python.analysis.extraPaths`, the only case I get the error is when I change something in `General` (add a `.py` file). I need to restart VSC, PyLance probably assumes the files in the `extraPaths` are static

Answer (score 59):

Pylance, by default, includes the root path of your workspace. If you want to include other subdirectories as import resolution paths, you can add them using the `python.analysis.extraPaths` setting for the workspace.

- In VS Code press `<ctrl> + <,>` to open Settings.
- Type in `python.analysis.extraPaths`
- Select "Add Item"
- Type in the path to your library `/home/andylu/Dokumente/Allgemeines_material/Sonstiges/Programming/Python/Scripts/`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yet, as you can see in my post, I've already tried that with no avail. Maybe it has an effect now. As soon as I get to try it out, I'll let you know.

Comment: Is there a less specific solution? I mean, if I use this solution, I have to add all the paths to all the folders where any test scripts are located.

Comment: I use virtualenv for my (Django) project and I had to reference the path for this to work: ~/.virtualenvs/<project directory>/Lib/site-packages/

Comment: In addition to this, make sure to [select and activate the correct Python environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment).

Comment: This works perfectly when the "source" folder is named something else than "src".

Comment: Doesn't work for me on macOS and latest version of vscode using Pylance. My conda envs work fine though.

Comment: This solution worked for me where I have installed pylucene to be running via jcc. Earlier, the auto completion for package, e.g. `from org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard import StandardAnalyzer` was not working. This solution worked for me after a restart of the vscode.

Answer (score 29):

Two methods below:

1. In VS code you can edit the `setting.json` file. If you add `"python.analysis.useImportHeuristic": true` the linting error will be removed.
2. The alternative is to add `# type: ignore` at the end of the import code.

Here is the github link that i got the above resolution from: https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/68

It worked for me: `python 3.9`, `VScode`, `windows10`

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I've also followed the git-discussion and saw the `"python.analysis.useImportHeuristic": true`, I'll try it out once I get to it. As for the 2nd alternative, this workaround was already mentioned in my initial post and seems to be the last resort, if nothing else works.

Comment: comment noted.  I confirm that both methods work on the setup that i have, although it seems that you are using `Lubuntu 20.04` whereas i tested on `windows10`. so would be useful to know that it is platform agnostic or otherwise.

Comment: Just checked it on Windows 10, in my `settings.json` the line `"python.analysis.useImportHeuristic": true` is greyed out. When I hover over it, it states "Unknown Configuration Setting".

Comment: @AndreasL. Same happened to me when I got the `"Unknown Configuration Setting"`. Did you find a workaround for this?

Comment: @PrakharRathi not yet, I'll let you know here if there are any updates

Comment: This is expected as it is a hidden option. https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/1167#issuecomment-822647493

Comment: I've revisited the issue today, and still there are import errors despite using `"python.analysis.useImportHeuristic": true` (see latest edit of my OP). I'll keep you guys updated.

Answer (score 6):

By default python selects the global interpreter as the interpreter for any python project you have. So the module/package resolution is in the global context. For any linter you are using to pick up your installed modules you have to ensure you select the correct interpreter

For instance, if you have ever worked with pycharm it does ask you to select the interpreter and create virtual environment with the selected interpreter. For the same, if you start a project in visual studio code It takes the global interpreter as the default interpreter even if you create a virtual environment See this on the bottom left section for the selected interpreter

[image]

So how do you ensure Pylance/Pylint/ reads modules installed in the virtual environment created? You need to check for the selected interpreter at the bottom left and if not activated on the virtual environment click on the selected interpreter and vs-code will prompt you to select a default interpreter for the project. Select your current virtual environment and visual studio pylance will read the modules in the current environment. Hope this works for anyone who's struggling with the same

[image]

[image]

Comment: This works, but some of us are also trying to add other sys.paths outside of the current env, and Pylance will not recognize them, even if they are setup correctly and work when we run the py files. [This Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10739838/3927293) was the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: You can add those paths in the `./vscode/settings.json` from where vscode reads all configurations from if the `settings.json` is set

Answer (score 2):

I was facing similar issue, even after having packages on my system, VS Code Pylance was not able to resolve imports.

In my case I had 2 different versions of python installed (one using anaconda distribution and other directly from python.org)

Fix: Select right python interpreter in VS code. Pylance will stop complaining :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to add an `.env` file at the root of the vscode project. For example:

`.env`

```
PYTHONPATH=src/mydir
```

You either use a relative path like above, or the full path. The benefit of `.env` is that it will fix both `pylance`  and `pylint` in vscode. And it's easier to commit and share on `git` than `.vscode/settings.json`.

Answer (score 1):

**Pylance** is the default the language server used for python project unless you specify it otherwise. If you get `(reportMissingImports)` and you are sure the dependency has been successfully installed, it means it's installed somewhere else than Pylance expected. This usually happens if you are working with virtual environements.

Pylance by default selects the **system python interpreter** for any python project, in this case you need to tell Pylance where to find the virtualenv python interpreter by defining this your **vscode settings**. Under `.vscode/settings.json` add the following:

```
{
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "~/.pyenv/versions/3.10.2/envs/<my-virtual-env-name>/bin/python",
    "python.linting.ignorePatterns": [
        "**/site-packages/**/*.py"
    ],
}
```

Now Pylance will know exactly where to look for the installed dependency. In my case I'm using `pyenv` but it may be any other path depending on what virtualenv tool you use. If you have other dependencies in other custom location, you can add them by specifying `"python.analysis.extraPaths"`:

```
{
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "~/.pyenv/versions/3.10.2/envs/<my-virtual-env-name>/bin/python",
    "python.linting.ignorePatterns": [
        "**/site-packages/**/*.py"
    ],
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "my-custom-path-1/python/scripts", 
        "my-custom-path-2/something-else"
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Anaconda environment, a workaround is to add your personal library path to 'python library path' via the command `conda develop path/to/your/module`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your settings.json in vscode:

```
   "python.analysis.extraPaths": ["ml/py"],
```

it can be a relative path based on the root of your project or an absolute path. You can also have several of them.

Answer (score -1):

In VS studio code

1. Open your folder
2. Right Click on the workspace where all the files or folders are
3. Add folder to workspace
4. Select the directory on what you inputted in `sys.path.insert("DIRECTORY")`

Comment: why would a Multi Root Workspace solve the PyLance `reportMissingImports` problem, where in Explorer do you `right click`? **Add Folder to Workspace** is part of the **File** menu