# import flask could not be resolved from source pylance

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

I'm learning Python and part of the course setting up a webserver using Flask. I followed the steps as per the Flask installation documentation and for some reason the flask module is underlined as shown below. When I hover my mouse, I get additional information as below.

> import flask could not be resolved from source pylance

The server is running fine though. Should i be ignoring the notification? If not what dependency have i missed?

Below is the code to setup the server

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
return 'Hello, World!'
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: it probably just means the python your editor is using is not the same interpreter that you're running when you run the server

Comment: Im using VS Code and installed Python 3.9.0 64 bit. What steps can i take to fix this please.

Comment: on the bottom left corner you should be able to see `Python 3.x.x`, click it, and make sure it is pointing to your system python

Comment: The system version is 2.7.16. When i select this interpreter, flask module still has the underline.

Comment: I came across the below link but not sure, what value i should assign for "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["./path-to-your-code"], in the vscode settings.json?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65252074/import-path-to-own-script-could-not-be-resolved-pylance-reportmissingimports

Comment: What if you're using venv? Can you tell VSCode to use that specific Python module?

Comment: Hope this link helps https://techinscribed.com/python-virtual-environment-in-vscode/

Comment: Peter - Yes, what you need to do is install the needed packages AFTER activating the virtual environment. For example, if "flask" module can't be resolved, first go to the terminal and run "env\Scripts\activate" if you called the virtual environment "env". Then install the package simply like "pip install flask". It will install the package into the virtual environment.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When I did not install the module "`flask`", I ran into the problem you described:

[image]

The reason is that the module "`flask`" is not installed in the Python environment we currently use in VSCode.

Please use the shortcut key Ctrl+Shift+` to open a new VSCode terminal, it will automatically enter the currently selected environment, and then use the command "*pip show flask*" to check the installation location of the module "flask":

[image]

If it still shows that the module could not be resolved, it is recommended that you reinstall the module "[flask](https://pypi.org/project/Flask/)".

Comment: Thanks Jill. Based on your solution, i noticed flask was installed in the project directory and not in the main python directory. I removed flask and reinstalled and its in the correct location as below:
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages

Answer (score 37):

1. Firstly, create a virtual environment on your terminal.
2. Then install Flask by running ***pip install flask***.
3. After installing, press ***CTRL+SHIFT+P***.
4. Search for *Python Interpreter*.
5. Select your virtual environment.

The problem will be fixed. I have also faced the same issue, but I resolved it by following this procedure.

Comment: It's important to note that if you navigate to the interpreter with the file browser, the symlinked interpreter will be selected, which won't fix the problem. Use a relative file path from your project folder instead, e.g., `../venv/bin/python` if your project folder is a sibling of your virtual environment.

Answer (score 8):

In VS Code, Go to "Python: Select interpreter" by Ctrl + Shift + P.
Choose python interpreter ('base': conda)

Answer (score 7):

This happens when the Python interpreter on VS Code is not the same as that in your virtual environment.
Click on the Python version on the lower left corner. In the "Select Interpreter" bar, select the venv Python or create a new interpreter path by copying the same from your Python file in the venv/bin directory.

Answer (score 5):

**go to your vs code terminal then type this command**

1. `sudo apt install python3-venv`
2. `python3 -m venv my-project-env`
3. `source my-project-env/bin/activate`
4. `pip install flask`
5. after install CTRL+SHIFT+P and search for Python Interpreter
   [image]
6. Select Your virtual Environment my-project-env which has created in above
   [image]
7. now check the output. problem will be solved like this.
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using a virtual environment;

1. Create a virtual environment.

   `python3.9 -m venv --without-pip virtual`
2. Activate the virtual environment.

   `source virtual/bin/activate`
3. Install the pip for the created virtual environment.

   `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python`
4. Install flask into the virtual env.

   `pip install flask`
5. Create the python file. For your case,

   `touch server.py`
6. Open file and import the module
7. If it underlines again, install pip again while the .py file is still open.

   `pip install flask`

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same situation until I changed the virtual environment of my VS Code to indicate the correct value that I should use:

[image: screenshot of my VSCode]

Answer (score 0):

All these answers are very helpful but if  you are still stuck
then try this method in which after creating a Virtual Environment we will select our interpreter path manually:

First open your project in VSCode.
Make Venv and then at right bottom of your editor see there is an option to select Python version like this:

[image: Link To Image]

Then click on python version and you can see window like this:

[image: Select Interpretor]

Then click on "Enter interpreter path"
and Select Interpreter that you created recently
which is located inside the scripts folder:

[image: Select Interpretor]

Hope this helps.
Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

*This answer is for posterity*

1. Check whether the `virtual env` is activated and the right interpreter selected (you can see this in bottom-right of VS code).
2. Check whether the dependency which you have installed is present in `virtual env` or not.
   ex: `pip show flask` in terminal should give the flask location in `virtual env` **not** global.
3. If above 2 steps didn't solve the problem then use `Ctrl+Shift+P` and type `reload window` and click it. This should solve the issue as it did for me.