# Import Error. I can't import mysql-connector in Python

Tags: python, mysql, module, pip, importerror

I have some problems trying to connect Python3 with MySql (8). I'm doing a programming course and the truth is that I still don't understand much.
I already have the mysql-connector-python module installed in my library.

`pip3 install mysql-connector-python`

Then when I try to import in Python 3 it won't let me do it.

`import mysql.connector`

> Import "mysql.connector" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports)

I already tried uninstalling and installing it again but it was not resolved. I tried to install other modules that I could see in different posts like *mysql-connector-python-r* but it didn't give me any results either.
I clarify that I have Windows, MySQL 8 and Python 3.

I thank you if you can help me to continue with my studies. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try solution from https://stackoverflow.com/q/65252074/4758312 ?

Comment: Yes and no, fix the error window problem but still can't call Python in GitBash, every time I try it tells me it can't find the module