# Import "odoo.addons.base_rest.controllers" could not be resolved. Pylance(reportMissingImports)

Tags: visual-studio-code, python-import, odoo-14, pylance

When i develop rest API for Addons odoo, set import and get problem

> Import "odoo.addons.base_rest.controllers" could not be resolved. Pylance(reportMissingImports)

this is a part of my code

```
from odoo.addons.base_rest.controllers import main 

class PrivateApiController(main.RestController):
   _root_path = '/api/private/helpdesk/'
   _collection_name = "private.helpdesk.service"
```

and all of code using **from odoo.addons.[module_name] import main** get problem **Pylance(reportMissingImports)** however when it runs, it doesn't matter

i use .env and my file structure is :

```
├── my_addons
│   ├── api_ticket [my addons that i develop and get problem Pylance Missing Report ]
|   |   ├── controllers
|   |   │   ├── controllers.py
|   |   │   ├── __init__.py
|   |   │   ├── main.py
|   |   │   └── __pycache__
|   |   ├── datamodels
|   |   │   ├── __init__.py
|   |   │   ├── __pycache__
|   |   │   └── ticket_datamodel.py
|   |   ├── demo
|   |   │   └── demo.xml
|   |   ├── __init__.py
|   |   ├── __manifest__.py
|   |   ├── models
|   |   │   ├── __init__.py
|   |   │   ├── models.py
|   |   │   └── __pycache__
|   |   ├── __pycache__
|   |   │   └── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
|   |   ├── security
|   |   │   └── ir.model.access.csv
|   |   ├── services
|   |   │   ├── __init__.py
|   |   │   ├── __pycache__
|   |   │   └── ticket_service.py
|   |   └── views
|   |       ├── templates.xml
|   |       └── views.xml
│   ├── auth_api_key
|   ├── base_rest [one of the imported modules and has been installed into the main odoo]
...
│   ├── helpdesk_type
│   my_odoo.conf
├── odoo-14.0 -> ~/P/OdooProject/odoo_base/odoo-14.0 [main odoo]
|   ├── LICENSE
|   ├── MANIFEST.in
|   ├── odoo
|   │   ├── addons
|   │   ├── api.py
...
|   └── setup.py
├── requirements.txt
├── runserver.sh
└── venv14 -> ~/P/OdooProject/odoo_base/venv14
```

then my setting.json

```
{
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "./odoo-14.0", // main odoo
        "./my_addons", // include develop addons and base_rest, etc from oca 
    ],
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "venv14/bin/python3"
    
}
```

i tried google the my problem and found ['Import "Path.to.own.script" could not be resolved Pylance (reportMissingImports)' in VS Code using Python 3.x on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65252074/import-path-to-own-script-could-not-be-resolved-pylance-reportmissingimports) and one of solution *The alternative is to add # type: ignore at the end of the import code.* as temporary solution

my question are :

1. Is there a main way to solve it ?
2. if one of the main ways is in the settings.json section and add python.analysis.extraPaths. is my writing correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Odoo loads addons dynamically as namespace packages and combines them into single namespace. Pylance on the other hand is a static analyzer. It doesn't execute any python code and therefore it is technically impossible to resolve those names. Unfortunately, I don't think there is a workaround this.

Answer (score 1):

How you organize your modules structure doesn't impacts how odoo organizes and makes them accessible.

Every odoo module will always be available inside `odoo.addons` namespace.
Your syntax looks correct for me, i think your module is being loaded before of `base_rest` so it is not accessible yet. Have you added `base_rest` as dependency in your `__manifest__.py` file?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your project depth from you call the import, try these in your settings project:

```
{

    "settings": {
        "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
            "/opt/odoo10/odoo",
            "....",
            "...",
            "..",
        
        ],
        "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
            "/opt/odoo10/odoo",
            "....",
            "...",
            "..",
        ],
    },

}
```